# integral over interval of length $2 \pi$

Tags: integration, periodic-functions

Let $f$ be a $2 \pi$ periodic function.
I think the integral of $f$ over $[a- \pi ,\; a+ \pi]$ is same as integral of $f$ over $[ -\pi , \; \pi]$. I.e. I think the integral is same in any interval of length $2\pi$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$F (x)=\int_0^xf (t)dt $$
and

$$G (a)=\int_{a-\pi}^{a+\pi}f (x)dx $$
$$=F (a+\pi)-F (a-\pi) $$

by FTC,
$$G'(a)=F'(a+\pi)-F'(a-\pi) $$
$$=f (a+\pi)-f (a-\pi) $$
$$=f (a+\pi-2\pi)-f (a-\pi)=0$$
thus
$G $ is constant and
$$G (a)=G (0)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f $$

Comment: What is FTC?I don't know the term.

Comment: Foundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: The proof is nice.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct.  You can break your interval at some odd multiple of $\pi$ into two pieces.  The integral over the bottom piece of your interval is equal to the integral over the top piece of the same length of $[-\pi,\pi]$ by the periodicity.  Similarly, the integral over the top piece of your interval is equal to the integral over the bottom piece of $[-\pi, \pi]$

Comment: Sir , if kundly write the proof completely it will be helpful for me.thanks for ur attention.

Comment: Draw a sketch using some arbitrary periodic function.  Can you see how I am suggesting to split the interval?  No, I won't write out the full proof.

Comment: Will you please elaborate it little more ? I am not getting your point.